# What is the image resize algorithm used by mobile apps like Flipboard, Facebook or Flickr

Tags: image, algorithm, mobile, resize

We are working on a mobile app similar to flipboard, we are currently using Bilinear algorithm, but the image clarity is not very clear (Blurred). Pls suggest..

Comment: Can you include some sample result you get with these apps for those that do not use them ? Also, by resizing do you mean downscaling or upscaling, or both ? If downscaling, this is quickly mentioned at http://stackoverflow.com/a/14116909/1832154. For upscaling, http://stackoverflow.com/a/13688592/1832154 links to at least two methods that are likely more robust than the typical bilinear, bicubic, lanczos.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what o/s you are using, but Android allows you to define different image assets to be used automatically for different screen resolutions. I would imagine that "professional apps" use this (or similar) to have different images for different screen resolutions, eliminating the need for rescaling. That's what I do, anyway.

Comment: But how do you produce those different image assets without resizing? It doesn't matter if the resizing happens on the client or the server, it must happen and the algorithm is of interest.